# How to return unicode response using callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord.js, unirest

I have been having trouble with retrieving the results of a query to an API back to a variable. I am trying to use a callback function but it is not working as expected.

My problem is that I am getting a response back from the API and I can see it outputted to the console when I log it, but it is still not being set to a variable, causing the variable to be undefined.

Here is the function making the query and its respective callback function

```js
function getResult(result)
{
    let gameInfo = result;
    //console.log(gameInfo); /// When uncommented, the response can be seen here, so I know my callback is getting the result.
    return gameInfo;
}
function queryRAWGDatabase(callback,title)
{
    title = title.split(' ').join('-');
    var req = unirest("GET", "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/" + title);

    req.headers({
        "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.RAWG_GAME_DATABASE_KEY,
        "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
        "useQueryString": true
    });
    req.end(function (result) {
        if (result.error)
        {
            return null;
        };
        return callback(result.body);
    });
}
```

And here is where I am calling the function and trying to set it to a variable.

```js
async function embedBuilder(message)
{
    await message.author.send("Lets get to work!\nPlease enter the title of your event. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)");
    const title = await collector(message,200);
    message.author.send("Please enter the name of the game. (Must be shorter than 200 characters)\nEnter \"None\" if this event does not have a game. ");
    const game_title = await collector(message,200,true);
    let game = queryRAWGDatabase(getResult,game_title); ////////////// CALL MADE HERE /////////
    message.author.send("Please enter a short description of your event. (Must be shorter than 2000 characters)\nEnter \"None\" if no. ");
    const description = await collector(message,2000,true);
    console.log(game); //// When I print it here, I get undefined!
    if (description != null)
    {
        var eventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle(title)
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .setDescription(description)
        .addField("Participants", "None")
        .addField("Not Attending", "None")
        .addField("Tentative", "None")
        .setImage(game.background_image);
    }
    else // Build embed without description
    {
        var eventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle(title)
        .setAuthor(message.author.username)
        .addField("Participants", "None")
        .addField("Not Attending", "None")
        .addField("Tentative", "None")
        .setImage(game.background_image);
    }
/// . . .
```

Finally, here are my errors.

```
(node:22974) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'background_image' of undefined
    at embedBuilder (/home/caleb/Programming/PlannerBot/commands/plan.js:80:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:22974) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22974) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is `game`? Is it a promise that needs to be "awaited"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to `await` `queryRAWGDatabase` function:

```js
let game = await queryRAWGDatabase(game_title)
```

> You don't need to have a callback if you await, so I removed `getResult`

However, at the moment this function is not await'able. To solve that, we need to edit that function so it would return a return [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance. It accepts callback with `resolve` & `reject` arguments. And you can call `resolve` to resolve the promise:

```js
function queryRAWGDatabase(title) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        title = title.split(' ').join('-');
        var req = unirest("GET", "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games/" + title);

        req.headers({
            "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.RAWG_GAME_DATABASE_KEY,
            "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
            "useQueryString": true
        });
        req.end(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                reject('Error: ' + result.error);
                return;
            };
            resolve(result.body);
        });
    })
}
```

> Instead of the callback, you need to call `resolve`. Regarding `result.error`, you can call `reject`, and then you will get an exception when awaiting.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I actually had about that exact code earlier, but I did not have the await keyword. I now see where my mistake was made. Can I ask if their is a reason a promise is used instead of a callback though? Is it better practice, or would a callback not work here?

Comment: For `await` to work, you need to return the promise instance. `await` essentially 'stops' your code until you get a response from that function. If you use callback (await won't work on that function, because it doesn't return promise) then code execution won't be stopped (unless you move all code bellow to the callback). As the result, you get undefined -> because below code executed before you finished your request.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification as well as the help.